# what is the best way to skew in x direction to look like this?

Tags: html, css

```css
.navbar{

 background-color: purple;
 width: 70%;
 height: 40px;
 transform: skewX(20deg);
 padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

I am trying to make a navigation bar that looks exactly the same as in image attached below.In the image the bottom ends of the div are skewed in X direction but when i tried this both corners skewed in the same direction.How to skew the div to look like this?

[image]

Comment: You could use `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to make those angled lines, skewing in opposite directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 85% 81%, 13% 80%);
```

Apply it your div now
You can change the values according to your needs.
Hope it help you.

Comment: Are you trying to skew the upper most div which I see is the whole purple colored box? Or you want the navbar div to be skew from bottom left and bottom right to the inner side?

If you can share your code here, that would be easy for everyone to help you.

Comment: yes.i want to skew the bottom corners of the purple div inside like the above image.I attached the code.

Comment: use this @Wania Kanwal
```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 85% 81%, 13% 80%);

Comment: You can also change the values according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You could try `clip-path` property instead of `transform`.

[Clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is a handy tool for creating css clip-paths, take a look